# LEFT JOIN help MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

**[Same post but with bit complicated issue]**

It should be simple but I am missing something.I have 2 tables

table_one (toneid is autoincrement with primary key)

```
  toneid   id       email
  1        634      45
  2        643      23
  3        648      55
```

table_two (tid is autoincrement with primary key)

```
tid
633
634
643
648
```

My desired result should be

```
tid      email
633      null
634      45
643      23
648      55
```

My query is

```
select table_two.tid, 
       table_one.id, 
       table_one.email 
from  table_two 
       left join table_one on table_one.id = table_two.tid
```

But it is returning

```
tid      email    
634      45
643      23
648      55
```

Comment: Or may be reverse the join i.e. `from  table_two

left join table_one  on table_one.id = table_two.tid`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it, just do the left join the other way around:

```
select table_two.tid, 
       table_one.id, 
       table_one.email 
 from  table_two 
       left join table_one on table_one.id = table_two.tid
```

Whe always has to read as this: Get all the content from the table that has more values and left join it with the one with might have registries associated. So in your case would be table_two left joined with table_one.

Comment: ahh...success. Thanks a ton mate. I have got bit complex thing coming in my way.So I will be posting a different question soon. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited the question.Now it is returning only 3 rows not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are in the wrong order.  Use `LEFT JOIN`, but make the first table the one where you want to keep all the records:

```
select  table_two.tid, table_one.id, table_one.email
from table_two left join
     table_one
     on table_one.id = table_two.tid;
```

I find the structure of using `left join`s to connect such tables is the most intuitive approach.  Personally, I have a very hard time understanding queries that mix left, right, and inner joins.  Usually what you have is a "driving" table, and making that first seems the clearest approach to writing a query.

Comment: Thanks Gordon for lovely explanation.

Comment: I have edited the question with new information.But for some reason the query is returning only 3 rows not 4 rows.